# Как ограничить доступ к sda для пользователя в группе disk в Linux?

Tags: linux, безопасность, файловая-система

На Пк имеется системный диск sda* и пользователь без `sudo`. Но он должен иметь возможность монтировать флешки самостоятельно и записывать их `dd`.
Но я хочу запретить ему записывать диск sda (чтобы он случайно не снес систему). А остальные флешки sde sdf ... пускай записывает как хочет.

Какой самый удобный и простой способ это сделать?

Comment: Флешки в десктопных линуксах обычно монтируются через udisks, а для ограничения доступа к sda наверно можно придумать какое-нибудь udev-правило

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создал правило в /etc/udev/rules.d/50-flash.rules

```
KERNEL=="sd[b-z]|sd[b-z][1-9]", MODE="0660", GROUP="flasher"
```

и группу flasher.

теперь диски выглядят так:

```
[user@pc ~]$ ls -la /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  0 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  1 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  2 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  3 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  4 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  5 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    8,  6 May 22 14:59 /dev/sda6
brw-rw---- 1 root flasher 8, 16 May 22 14:59 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root flasher 8, 32 May 22 14:59 /dev/sdc
brw-rw---- 1 root flasher 8, 33 May 22 14:59 /dev/sdc1
brw-rw---- 1 root flasher 8, 48 May 22 14:59 /dev/sdd
brw-rw---- 1 root flasher 8, 64 May 22 14:59 /dev/sde
```